# Crear usuarios con devise desde otro controlador Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Estoy usando devise para la autentificacion del usuario y estoy intentando crear view admin que pueda crear usuarios desde esa view.

Cosas a saber:

Estoy usando el ApplicationHelper para poder logear desde el home en vez de usar el login por defecto.

La idea es que el admin pueda crear los usuarios con otros roles (listo, configurado y en funcionamiento con CANCAN)  por eso esta vista incluirá en el form el campo role.

ApplicationHelper:

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def resource_name
   :user
  end
  def resource_name_request
   :request
  end

 def resource
   @resource ||= User.new
 end

 def devise_mapping
   @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
 end

end
```

admin_controller: Si lo hago de manera estatica funciona ese insert pero no toma las variables del form

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
      before_action :authenticate_user!
  def index
#    @user = User.new(:email => 'test@example.com',
#                     :password => 'password',
#                     :password_confirmation => 'password') funciona pero no toma las variables del form

    @user = User.new(admin_params)
    @user.save
  end

  private

  def admin_params
  #  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :role])
    params.require(:admin).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :role)
  end
end
```

index.html.erb: Vista de mi controller Admin

```
<div id="conteiner_admin">
      <div class="container">
        <div align="center">
          <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
          <%= devise_error_messages! %>

          <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :name %><br />
            <%= f.text_field :name %>
          </div>

          <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :email %><br />
            <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
          </div>

          <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :password %>
            <% if @minimum_password_length %>
            <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
            <% end %><br />
            <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
          </div>

          <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
            <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
          </div>

            <div class="field">

              <%= f.select(:role) do %>
                <% [['Admin', "admin"], ['User', "user"]].each do |c| -%>
                  <%= content_tag(:option, c.first, value: c.last) %>
                <% end %>
              <% end %>
            </div>

            <div class="actions">
                <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
            </div>
          <% end %>
        </div>

      </div>
</div>
```

Mi Problema principal mente es que no entiendo por que strong parameters no capta mi form dando error:

ActionController::ParameterMissing in AdminController#index

Me gustaria saber si es algo malo en el controller o es mi problema con el strong parameters

Comment: ¿Ya solucionaste? Observo es que estas realizando un `PUT` cuando para **CREAR** debería ser `POST` en el formulario. Saludos!

Comment: @iTox gracias y si ya solucione

Answer (score 1):

en tus strong paremeters, le estas indicando que la clave es **admin**, cuando en la vista en el  formulario la clave corresponde a **user**, el cual lo has inicializado  en tu **AplicationHelper**, como **resource_name**

intenta cambiar

params.require(:admin).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :role)

por

params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :role)

cabe mencionar que debes verifica tus rutas, a ver si el método index corresponde al verbo post de tu formulario con el comando

**rake routes**